Any tips regarding overcoming mental barriers to being a better Muslim
Salam
I reverted summer of 2022 alhamdulilah but certain mental disorders (not illnesses so they have no cure) have made practicing Islam quite difficult. My social abilities and confidence are greatly affected and so I haven’t managed to reach out to any Muslim communities offline. I’m in a few online spaces but still find it nerve-wracking even with the anonymity. Also my memory is greatly affected and despite my best efforts I still haven’t memorised salah and I (rather awkwardly) read off of an app on my phone, picking it up and holding it in my hand stood up and back on the floor when I’m on my knees, only the takbir and sujood I have managed to keep in memory.
I know that certain obligations (such as attending the masjid for Friday prayer) are held with leniency against those with conditions they cannot help, but I still wish I’d find it easier. I wish I had a strong real life Muslim community and I found memorising the rakats easy and actually possible. Just wondering if anyone else has experienced this/known someone who experienced this and ways to remedy either the barriers or guilt :)
Thank you

Actually this website is a QA website, so that you are expected to ask a specific question that expects a specific answer. I couldn't understand a specific question in yours, to b able to answer to.  However, maybe you should not feel guilty at all, as Islam does not expect from you more than you can bear it, if you do your best that would be fine, and maybe you can learn more and improve practicing Islam in the course of time.
